# Get data from second subpage to first page - Windows Phone(best approach)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I want to ask you, what do you think, what is the best approach to get from second page to first page? I use something like this.(MVVM)

Second page:

```
public partial class AddProfilePageView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public AddProfilePageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new AddProfileViewModel();
    }

    public AddProfileViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as AddProfileViewModel; } }}
```

First page:

```
public partial class ProfilesPageView : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public ProfilesPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ProfilesViewModel();
    }

    public ProfilesViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as ProfilesViewModel; }
    }}
```

AddProfileViewModel() class has properties, that are binded to controls in xaml. From this page I need to get data to first page ProfilesPageView.

My solution is:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var content = e.Content as ProfilesPageView;
        if (content != null && ViewModel.IsOk)
        {
                content.ViewModel.ProfilesList.Add(ViewModel.ProfileRecord);

        }
    }
```

So what do you think? Is it good solution how obtain data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In reality here you're not trying to get data from one page to another.
On the second/detail page you're adding a new item and then when you return to the first/main page you want it to update the displayed data to show the new item.

I'd assume that `AddProfileViewModel` and `ProfilesViewModel` are both persisting to disk/IsolatedStorage so you could just refresh the main/list/first page when returning to it.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    // ...

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        (this.DataContext as ProfilesViewModel).Refresh();
    }
}
```